# Keystore - Как получить пароль из файла

Tags: android, keystore

**Android Studio** (сейчас), а ранее он был разработан в другой среде и данный проект был импортирован в Android Studio.

Имеется *файл* содержащий пароль, но неизвестен этот пароль.

Я знаю способ, подбора паролей, но это достаточно долго, есть ли другие возможности?

Как получить пароль из файла keystore? (Это не взлом, восстановление пароля).
Речь идёт об подписи APK.

Comment: Если вы пользовались Android Studio и у вас она осталась (главное лог файлы), то восстановить можно по ним. Через файл не восстановить.

Comment: Если это keystore для подписи apk-файла, то никакого пароля внутри нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Молодой человек:

1. KeyStore не содержит пароль
2. KeyStore не содержит пароль
3. KeyStore не содержит пароль
   ....

Спецификация контента KeyStore [примерно такая](http://keystore-explorer.org/specifications.html)